# Remove view from superview

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I remove this collectionview from superview when the view disappear, because of memory issue, but I want to add add it back when the view appear, I just want to add it back! or is there another way to do it? Thanks.

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
       let subViews = self.view.subviews
       for subview in subViews{
           if subview.tag == 1 {
              subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }        
    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
 var savedView: UIView?

 override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    let subViews = self.view.subviews
    for subview in subViews{
        if subview.tag == 1 {
            savedView = subview
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}




override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if let subview = savedView {
        view.addSubview(subview)
        savedView = nil
    }
}
```

But it doesn't add it back.

Comment: Are you sure the tag is 1 for that subview, and that the subview is being removed appropriately and that savedView is not nil after the save?

Comment: Yes the collectionview is removed but I can't add it back. And when I print() the subview in view did disappear the collectionview is saved.

Comment: Is this a `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: No it's not. What if I create the collectionview from code, will it work? I could create it in viewWillAppear and remove it in viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 1):

Create an optional property in your view controller. Assign the found subview to this optional property in your `viewDidDisappear` method. Then in the `viewWillAppear` method you can check if the optional property is set or not. If set, add it back as a subview.

Add this property:

```
var savedView: UIView?
```

Then do this in `viewDidDisappear`:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
   // This assumes there is no other deep subview with a tag of 1
   // If this isn't true, use your current for-loop to find the subview
   if let subview = subviews.viewWithTag(1) {
       savedView = subview
       subview.removeFromSuperview
   }
}
```

And do this in `viewWillAppear`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   if let subview = savedView {
       addSubview(savedView)
       savedView = nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, but it did not work. I just update my question. Do you have other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You didn't declare `savedView` like I did in my answer.

Comment: Sorry I just update the question. But it still doesn't work

Comment: The subview is removed and saved successfully but I can't put it back.

Comment: Is the call to `addSubview` reached or not? If it is but the collection view doesn't seem to appear, try reloading the collection view after adding it back.

Comment: Still nothing and there's no crash.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is the call to `addSubview` being reached?

Comment: Yes it is being reached

Comment: Make savedView global. This is not a very good solution but it should work. Why exactly do have to do this? A memory issue should not occur because iOS should take care of it.

Comment: @Lenny1357 Why are you suggesting that `savedView` be a global? I already stated to make it a property of the class. Making it a global is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: I agree with you that it's not a good thing to do but that way you could keep your view and show it as it was even in new insurances of MainTVC. You should also not always create a new instance of MainTVC.

Comment: @Lenny1357 I have no idea what you mean. And again, making `savedView` a global is pointless. Using a property is the correct solution.

Comment: A global variable wouldn't change with creating new instances of MainTVC. If it's a class variable it sticks to one instance of that class and cannot be accessed by others. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Lenny1357 That's what I suggested in my answer. That's what a property is. You keep using the term global. That's something different from what I suggested. That's the confusion. You are misusing the term "global".

Comment: No, I am not. What I portrayed in my previous comment is the problem so making savedView global would be a way (not a good one) to solve it